# Proving if $f$ is UC on a bounded set $S$, then $f$ is bounded function on $S$.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, continuity, uniform-continuity

Here's what I need to prove:

> if $f$ is uniformly continuous on a bounded set $S$, then $f$ is
>   a bounded function on $S$.

I plan on using this theorem:
If $f$ is uniformly continuous on a set $S$ and $(s_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $S$, then $(f(s_n))$ is a Cauchy sequence.

Here's my attempt:

Assume that $f$ is not bounded on $S$, then for every $M>0$, there is $x \in S$ such that $|f(x)|>M$. It follows that there is a sequence $(s_n)$ in $S$ such that $|f(s_n)|  > n$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Now, since $(s_n)$ is bounded (because $S$ is bounded), by the Bolzano Weierstrass Theorem, there is an convergent subsequence $(s_{n_{k}})$. Since, $(s_{n_{k}})$ is convergent, it is Cauchy as well. However, $|f(s_{n_{k}})|$ does not converge to a finite value and hence is not Cauchy. This contradicts that theorem.

Is this proof correct or do I go wrong somewhere?

Comment: It looks fine to me.

Comment: You have to make precise what kind of a function $f$ is. It seems $f : S \to \mathbb{R}$, but what is $S$? A subset of  $ \mathbb{R}$?